# Массовая замена кода

Tags: html

У заказчика сайт на html. Имеется 100+ страниц. На всех нужно изменить одну и ту же часть html кода. Есть ли способ чтобы сделать это массово не в ущерб качеству?:

Спасибо....

Comment: Просто они переехали и теперь адрес на страницах должен быть другим.....

Comment: в любом современном IDE есть поиск и замена по всем совпадениям, качаете все 100+ страниц, меняете адрес, выгружаете обратно

Comment: Нашел как можно это делать массово через sublime, буду пробовать, думаю, что не актуально уже. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем Sublime - выбираем Find in files и творим красоту) много времени сэкономил этот способ)